# Como criar uma lista dinâmica encadeada dentro de outra lista dinâmica em C?

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou com uma enorme dificuldade para conseguir criar uma lista encadeada dinamicamente dentro de outra usando estrutura de dados. Sei criar uma lista dinâmica, porem não consigo criar outra dentro dela.

Para exemplificar o que quero dizer:

Tenho uma lista de *Bandas*; cada *banda* é uma lista de *albuns*; e cada *album* é uma lista de *musica*. E no programa o usuário pode incluir musicas e remove-las quando quiser, incluir álbuns e remove-las quando quiser, e incluir bandas e remove-las quando quiser.

Meu código está assim, mas não funciona, *deve ter muita coisa sem sentido*:

### Arquivo .C

```c
#include "biblioteca.h"

ElemM *lm;
ElemA *la;
ElemB *lb;
//---------------------------MAIN--------------------------------->

int main()
{
  lb = cria_lista_banda();
  la =  cria_lista_album();
  lm = cria_lista_musica();


  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
} 
//----------------------------------------------------------------->

ElemB *cria_lista_banda(){
        ElemB *lb;
        lb =  malloc(sizeof(ElemB));
        lb->prox_banda = NULL;
        return lb;


}

ElemA *cria_lista_album(){
        ElemA *la;
        la =  malloc(sizeof(ElemA));
        la->prox_album= NULL;
        return la;


}

ElemM *cria_lista_musica(){
        ElemM *lm;
        lm =  malloc(sizeof(ElemM));
        lm->prox_musica= NULL;
        return lm;


}

int incluir_musica(ElemM *lm, ElemA *la, ElemB *lb, int id_m, int tempo, char *nome_m, int id_a, int id_b){
        int valor1, valor2, valor3, i;

        valor1 = busca_banda(id_b, lb);
        valor2 = busca_album(id_b, id_a, lb, la);
        valor3 = busca_musica(id_b, id_a, id_m, lb, la, lm);
        if(valor3 == -1) return -1;

        ElemB *q;
        q = lb->prox_banda;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor1; i++){
              q = q->prox_banda;
        }
        ElemA *p;
        p = q->albuns_da_banda->prox_album;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor2; i++){
             p = p->prox_album;         
        }

        ElemM *novo, *novocpy;
        p->musicas_do_album->novo = malloc( sizeof(ElemM));
        novocpy = p->musica_do_album->novo;
        if(novo == NULL) return 0;
        novocpy->id_musica = id_m;
        novocpy->tempo_da_musica = tempo;
        strcpy(novocpy->nome_musica, nome_m);
        novocpy->prox_musica = lc->prox_musica;
        lm->prox_musica = novocpy;
        return 1;
}

int busca_banda(int id, ElemB *lb){
        int cont = 0;
        ElemB *p;
        p = lb->prox_banda;
        while(p != NULL && p->id_banda != id){
                p = p->prox_banda;
                cont++;
        }
        if(p == NULL) return -1;
        return cont;
}

int buscar_album(int id_b, int id_a, ElemB *lb, ElemR *la){
        int valor_busca = busca_banda(id_b, lb); 
        int i;
        int cont = 0;

        if(valor_busca == -1) return -1;
        ElemB *q;
        q = lb->prox_banda;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor_busca; i++){
              q = q->prox_banda;
        }
        ElemA *p;
        p = q->albuns_da_banda->prox_album;
        while(p != NULL && p->id_album != id_a){
             p = p->prox_album;
             cont++;         
        }      

        if(p != NULL) return -1;
        return cont;   

}


int buscar_musica(int id_b, int id_a, int id_m, ElemB *lb, ElemA *la, ElemM *lm){
        int valor_busca1 = busca_banda(id_b, lb);
        int valor_busca2 = busca_album(id_b, id_a, lb, la); 
        int i;
        int cont = 0;

        if(valor_busca1 == -1) return -1;
        if(valor_busca2 == -1) return -1;
        ElemB *q;
        q = lb->prox_banda;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor_busca1; i++){
              q = q->prox_banda;
        }
        ElemA *p;
        p = q->albuns_da_banda->prox_album;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor_busca2; i++){
             p = p->prox_album;         
        }
        ElemM *k;
        k = p->musica_do_album->prox_musica;
        while(k != NULL && k->id_musica != id_m){
             k = k->prox_musica;
             cont++;         
        }       

        if(k != NULL) return -1;
        return cont;   

}
```

### Arquivo .h

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct musica{
       int id_musica;
       int tempo_musica;
       char nome_musica[30];
       struct casa *prox_musica;
       };      

typedef struct casa ElemM;

struct album{
       int id_album;
       char nome_album[30];
       struct casa *musica_do_album;
       struct rua *prox_album;
       };

typedef struct album ElemA;

struct banda{
       int id_banda;
       char nome_banda[30];
       struct album *albuns_da_banda;
       struct banda *prox_banda;
       };       

typedef struct banda ElemB;


ElemB *cria_lista_banda();
ElemR *cria_lista_album();
ElemC *cria_lista_musica();
int incluir_musica(ElemM *lm, ElemA *la, ElemB *lb, int id_m, int tempo, char *nome_m, int id_a, int id_b)
int busca_banda(int id, ElemB *lb);
int buscar_album(int id_b, int id_a, ElemB *lb, ElemR *la);
int buscar_musica(int id_b, int id_a, int id_m, ElemB *lb, ElemA *la, ElemM *lm);
```

@pedro-witzel e @hugomg , os arquivos acima foram editados para como estão agora. Não estão funcionando e as fontes que estou usando para tentar resolver este problema não falam sobre lista dentro de outra, e não consigo encontrar nada relacionada a isto, apenas de como fazer uma lista encadeada "normal", poderiam me ajudar mais uma vez?

Obs: O valor -1 indica que alguma coisa aconteceu e fez o programa não atingir o objetivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumindo que cada música só pode estar em um único album e que cada album só pode pertencer a uma única banda, o notmal seria fazer cada nó album conter um ponteiro para a primeira música de sua lista e que fazer cada nó banda conter um ponteiro para o primeiro álbum de sua lista.

O ponteiro para o primeiro elemento de uma lista encadeada é a maneira de armazenar a lista.

```
struct banda {
    int id_banda;
    char nome_banda[50];
    struct album *albums_da_banda;
    struct banda *prox_banda;
};

struct album {
    int id_album;
    char nome_album[50];
    struct musica *musicas_do_album;
    struct album *prox_album;
};

struct musica {
    int id_musica;
    char nome_musica[50];
    struct musica *prox_musica;
};
```

Quanto ao "tem coisa sem sentido", não sou muito fã de typedefs como "Elemento_album" e "ListaAlbuns". Tem gente que gosta mas eu acho que fica confuso quando um typedef esconde o fato de algo ser um ponteiro.

Normalmente eu faço só um typedef pra não ter que ficar digitando "struct" toda hora.

```
typedef struct album {
     ...
} album;
```

Mas as regras pra esse tipo de typedef são um pouco confusas quando você tem estruturas recursivas. No seu caso acho que talvez seja mais fácil deixar sem typedef por enquanto.

Outra sugestão paralela é usar letra maiúscula no nome dos seus tipos. Assim dé pra ver logo de cara o que é um tipo qe o que é uma variável no seu programa.

```
struct Album { ... };
```

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi muito bem como ficaria o arquivo .h. As informações da struct musica que estava .h, agora vão ficar nesse novo struct musica que você escreveu? Obrigado

Comment: Poderia me da uma dica de como continuar meu programa? De como criar funções para incluir e eliminar da lista? Muito obrigado.

Comment: As declaraçÕes de tipo que eu sugeri vão no ".h". Já as funções para inserir elementos novos sugiro que você tente fazer sozinho. Se eu fizer tudo perde a graça :)

Comment: Irei tentar :) - Mas você não teria algo para ler ou algum video que aborde esse tema? Obrigado

Comment: Lista encadeada é o tipo de coisa que você vai achar em quase qualquer material introdutório. Acho melhor o que você já estiver usando. Se quiser ir mais a fundo, ache um bom livro de estruturas de dados (como o do Sedgewick)

Comment: Dei uma editada no codigo para como ficou agora e no texto, poderia dar uma olhada? Grato. –

Comment: Se estiver funcionando não precisa eu dar uma olhada :) Se não tiver, é melhor fazer uma pergunta separada ao invés de continuar editando essa aqui. Assim mais gente pode ajudar. E como sempre, tente fazer perguntas objetivas e deixe claro qual erro está ocorrendo.

Answer (score 1):

As variáveis `prox_*` tem o nome errado, o que pode levar a confusão. 
Por exemplo, `prox_musica` é tipado com `album`.

Se a intenção é criar listas encadeadas, o ideal é que a variável tenha um ponteiro para outra do mesmo tipo.

Entao, o struct `musica` ficaria:

```
struct musica{
       int id_musica;
       int tempo_da_musica;
       char nome_musica[30];
       struct musica *prox_musica;
       };
```

E o struct do album seria

```
struct album{
         int id_album;
         char nome_album[50];
         struct musica *primeira_musica;
         struct album *prox_album;
         };
```

Idem para os outros structs. 
Perceba que mudei o nome de `dados_musica` para `primeira_musica` e seu tipo para um ponteiro.

Quando for fazer o laço para percorrer as musicas de um álbum, pegue o ponteiro da primeira musica para começar, e a cada iteração, pegue o próximo ate que ele seja `null`

```
for (struct musica *pMusica = album.primeira_musica; 
     pMusica != NULL;
     pMusica = pMusica->prox_musica)
{
   ///Faça o que quiser
}
```

Para adicionar uma nova entrada em uma lista encadeada é necessário primeiro criar o novo objeto e atualizar o anterior com sua referencia:

```
struct musica nova_musica;
musica_anterior.prox_musica = &nova_musica;
```

Caso tenha alocado os objetos na pilha terás que percorrer todas as listas recursivamente (desde a produtora, no teu caso) para liberar o espaço criado.

```
struct musica *pMusica = album.primeira_musica; 
while (pMusica != NULL)
{
    struct musica *pProx_musica = pMusica->prox_musica;
    free(pMusica);
    pMusica = pProx_musica;
}
```

Fonte: [IME-USP](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html)

Comment: Você poderia da umas dicas de como criar função de exclusão da lista no fim do programa, ou mesmo da inclusão de elementos? Estou tentando criar elas aqui, porem geram muitos erros que acabo demorando muito para consertar. Muito obrigado

Comment: @JoãoM.Silva, atualizei a resposta. Mas como nao sei exatamente o que quer, dei respostas meio abertas. Se ainda tiver duvidas, de uma olhada no link da fonte, o material é interessante.

Comment: Estou utilizando o material que está no link da fonte pra tentar fazer este programa, mas ainda não estou conseguindo entender como fazer pra inserir/buscar uma musica no album certo e na banda certa,  mesmo com sua ajuda anterior. Estou com uma dificuldade muito grande para conseguir fazer isso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Dei uma editada no codigo para como ficou agora e no texto, poderia dar uma olhada? Grato.

Answer (score -1):

> Estou com uma enorme dificuldade para conseguir criar uma lista
> encadeada dinamicamente dentro de outra usando estrutura de dados. Sei
> criar uma lista dinâmica, porem não consigo criar outra dentro dela

O problema está aí mesmo: uma lista é um *container*, e não deveria fazer diferença o que tem dentro dela. Se faz diferença é porque está escrito errado. Uma lista de listas, uma lista de bandas, de albums, de músicas, de listas de listas de listas. Tanto faz.

#### Exemplo do código original:

```
struct musica
{
    int          id_musica;
    int          tempo_musica;
    char         nome_musica[30];
    struct casa* prox_musica;
};

typedef struct casa ElemM;

struct album
{
    int          id_album;
    char         nome_album[30];
    struct casa* musica_do_album;
    struct rua*  prox_album;
};

typedef struct album ElemA;

ElemA* cria_lista_album();
ElemM* cria_lista_musica();
```

A nomenclatura realmente é estranha. O que seria `casa`? Mas não importa.

- criar uma lista é criar uma lista. Nada tem a ver com o conteúdo. Não pode ser diferente criar uma lista de album ou de musica ou de espaçonaves
- a noção de música, album ou banda NADA tem a ver com a lista. A lista é um container de nós. De "células" como aparece no link incluído na pergunta original. Só que no código mostrado não tem um ponteiro para célula. Parece que o conceito não foi levado a sério. Cada elemento da lista contém ou aponta para um dado. Esse dado geralmente tem um campo que é chamado de chave, e que implementa uma relação de ordem na lista.
- uma lista não é uma célula. Uma célula não é uma lista. Uma célula não é o dado, apenas aponta para ele. Falhar em manter essa separação é o que gera essa dificuldade na implementação.

#### Exemplo: `Musica` `Album` e `Banda`

- Os campos `id` estão dentro de cada estrutura: não há razão para qualificar mais. Basta `id`.
- Um album tem uma lista de `Musica`. É o que basta. Um ponteiro.
- Uma banda tem uma lista de albums. É o que basta: um ponteiro.

```
typedef struct
{
    int  id;
    int  tempo_musica;
    char nome_musica[30];

} Musica;

typedef struct
{
    int    id;
    char   nome_album[30];
    Lista* M;  // as musicas

} Album;

typedef struct
{
    int    id;
    char   nome_banda[30];
    Lista* A; // os albums

} Banda;
```

#### E a `Lista` afinal?

Não tem lista sem células.

```
typedef struct st_cell
{
    void*           info;
    struct st_cell* ant;
    struct st_cell* prox;

} Celula;
```

Agora tem a tal célula. info pode ser a música, a banda ou o sorteio da loteria. Só um ponteiro e a vida segue.

Mas podemos escrever a `Lista` afinal

```
typedef struct
{
    int     N;       // tamamho
    int     limite;  // opcional
    Celula* inicio;
    Celula* fim

} Lista;
```

Numa implementação real falta a noção de ordem, para poder inserir e buscar valores pela ordem.

Mas para um exercício isso basta.

#### listas "duplamente ligadas"

Essa não é uma tradução feliz. Seria melhor algo como "listas com ligações duplas".

Entenda que as listas com ponteiro para um lado só são MUITO mais difíceis de programar do que as que tem dois, e não o contrário.

Esse aqui é um bom exemplo: é óbvio querer navegar na lista de músicas de um album, mas se só tem ponteiros para um lado é um inferno. Remover algo é mais difícil. Tudo é mais difícil.

Não vou escrever as funções porque são simples e foge da pergunta.